# VBA MS Access code wont run

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am very new to vba and I am trying to get my first bit of VBA code to run, I have added a button to a form. I then opened the on click event and placed

```
Private Sub run_Click()
MsgBox "hello World"
End Sub`
```

into the module but when I go back into the form and click the button in form view nothing happens, I am doing something wrong, i have tryed to run lots of other sniptes of code but nothing is working, I am kinda unsure how I actaully "run" the code.

[image]

I Click run then I get this

[image]

I have gone to the trust centre and Enabled Macros and still I get this error ??

// This issue has been solved my marcos were not enabled in the trust centre

Comment: Make sure your button is called run and your are not using a reserved name to name it. Try `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() MsgBox "hello World" End Sub`

Comment: Yes im sure the button name and vba code match, I have uploaded a photo to show you! i have followed a few differnt tutorials and still nothing works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a brand new database then it may not be "trusted" yet. Exit Access completely, then try opening the database again. if you see a warning like...

> Security Warning: Some active content has been disabled.

...along with an "Enable Content" button then click that button (to enable macros and VBA code) and then try your form again.

Comment: Thank you so much this has solved my problem! once I restarted access after Enabling content it worked ! This problem has casued me so many headaches !

Comment: @user2339714: lol, you have tired to change a flat tire without lifting the car up haha good luck in your VBA adventure

Answer (score 1):

In your VBA editor do this:

1. Create a userform and rename it to **yourFormName**
   [image: Rename your form]
2. Create a button on the form and rename it to **yourButton**
   [image: Rename your button]
3. Double-click your button and paste the below 

   `Private Sub yourButton_Click()`
              `MsgBox "hello world"` 
         `Me.Hide`
    `End Sub`
4. Insert a module and paste this code in 

     `Sub RunMain()`
           `With yourFormName`
               `yourFormName.Show`
               `Unload yourFormName`
      `End With`
       `End Sub`
5. Run the RunMain macro and then click the button!

Answer (score 1):

When MS Access first opens on your desktop and it has VBA within, you'll need to enable that code.  In MS Access 2010, File --> Options --> Trust Center --> Macro Settings as well as ActiveX Settings.  The security nanny-statists have set the default so VBA will not run unless you specifically allow it.